# What's the meaning of characteristic in "characteristic polynomial"?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, soft-question, terminology

Why the polynomial that has the eigenvalues as roots called characteristic? 
Is there any special meaning in the term "characteristic"?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Characteristic.html

Comment: For some historical context for use of "characteristic" as it relates to eigenvalues and such, see the ["Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics" pages](http://jeff560.tripod.com/e.html) under "eigenvalue".

Comment: Eigenvalues are sometimes called "characteristic values."